# install screen from source code

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, redhat-enterprise-linux

I tried to install the `screen` command on RedHat from source code. But when I run the `configure`, it returned

```
configure: error: !!! no tgetent - no screen
```

So does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Google Fu says this: http://www.linuxsolved.com/forums/index.php?topic=234.0 (missing `termcap`)

Comment: I have tried the method. It didn't work.

Comment: I believe you need package `ncurses-devel`.

Answer (score 8):

You should install package `ncurses-devel` -- Should be done via `sudo yum install ncurses-devel`

Answer (score 4):

This answer suits well for those needing to install ncurses also from source, also in a local folder:

- Download ncurses:

  ```
  wget "https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.1.tar.gz"
  ```
- untar and enter folder

  ```
  tar zvxf ncurses-6.1.tar.gz
  cd ncurses-6.1
  ```
- Install:

  ```
  ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local  # or $HOME/.local
  make
  make install
  ```
- before making the same for screen, export this as:

  ```
  export LDFLAGS='-L$HOME/local/lib'
  export CPPFLAGS='-I$HOME/local/include'
  ```
- screen download and install:

  ```
  cd ~
  wget "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/screen-4.8.0.tar.gz"
  tar xzvf screen-4.8.0.tar.gz
  mkdir $HOME/local/etc # for install below
  cd screen-4.8.0

  ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local
  # if you got tgetent error use real path instead of $HOME
  make install &&
  install -m 644 $HOME/screen-4.8.0/etc/etcscreenrc $HOME/local/etc/screenrc

  export PATH="$HOME/local/bin:$PATH"
  ```

Related to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348184/can-not-find-screen-and-how-to-install-it-without-network-and-administration

Source: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/screen.html

Answer (score 1):

I installed `libncurses5-dev` on Ubuntu 14.04 to fix the issue - as I received the same error message.

I ran `sudo rm -fR autom4te.cache` in the same directory, `Makefile` was then created, then smooth sailing.

Answer (score -2):

You need to install `libncurses5-dev` and then try your configure -> make process again.

Exec this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Comment: Although I believe your answer is correct, you should include some more information on why your answer solves the question. Like why you suggest to install that specific package etc.